# Python 3 Timedelta OverflowError

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, datetime, overflow

I have a large database that I am loading into an in-memory cache. I have a process that does this iterating through the data day by day.

Recently this process has started throwing the following error:

`OverflowError: date value out of range` for the line

`start_day = start_day - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)`

This is running in Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.5

Comment: What is the initial value of start_day?

Comment: `datetime.utcnow().date()` when the process starts running

Answer (score 9):

You have reached [`datetime.date.min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.min), or the first of January of the year 1:

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> date.min
datetime.date(1, 1, 1)
>>> date.min - timedelta(days=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: date value out of range
```

If you started at `datetime.date.today()`, then it took your code a little over 736k steps to get there:

```
>>> date.today().toordinal()
736766
```

Your code probably has a bug somewhere that is subtracting too often.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome error you may change

```
datetime.date(1, 1, 1)
```

to more greater values like

```
datetime.date(2, 2, 2)
```

but if you edit Time column for example note that your date in this column is artificial 2, 2, 2 or something

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually funny, mine was overflow error but was datetime.date.max

My mistake was simple

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
increment = timedelta(days=1)
i = 0
while i <= 30:
    today += increment
    yield today
```

The problem about this code is that I did not increase i at the end of the loop, so it continued to run till `today`(datetime) maxed out.

You should also lookout for errors like this.

To debug the above code, I made sure `i` is increased at the end of the loop block

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
increment = timedelta(days=1)
i = 0
while i <= 30:
    today += increment
    yield today
    i++
```

Answer (score -1):

if you face this issue while reading excel/csv file using pandas, then check your excel/csv file, any one or more column will have the values like #############, that means value is negative ex: (-11111) or date is too long to fit in the cell

```html
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file path,dtype='string') #this will convert all the column 
     type to string

or if you want to convert specific column then 

df = pd.read_excel(file path,converters={'column name':str})
```