# The excel file is getting corrupted after saving it using pd.ExcelWriter

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

After using the below code the excel file is getting corrupted and MS excel asks to recover the file.

```
    def data_to_excel(self, df):

    logging.info("Process of saving data started.")
    with FileManager(self.lable.BRI_EXCEL_PATH_DEAD) as book:
        # book = load_workbook(self.lable.BRI_EXCEL_PATH_DEAD)
        # UPDATE
        options = dict()
        options['strings_to_formulas'] = False
        options['strings_to_urls'] = False
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(self.lable.BRI_EXCEL_PATH_DEAD, engine='openpyxl', options=options)
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=self.lable.SHEETNAME)

        writer.save()
        writer.close()
    book.close()
    logging.info("Process of saving data completed.")
```

Comment: How many rows do you want to write to the excel?

Comment: The maximum number of rows and columns on a worksheet: 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns

Comment: rows are 60K and column 15

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263547/python-3-timedelta-overflowerror

Comment: If you have resolved the initial problem, please update the question and provide more information. 60k rows * 15 columns is a fairly small worksheet and should be processed in less than a minute.